# How to update or change the entire propery of a particular redux object

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit, react-hook-form, immer.js

Am having issues updating a redux store in NEXTJS. am building a CV platform with the feature to preview users' input almost immediately into a preview page. this cv platform has the experience, education etc that a normal cv platform should have and am using the react hook form package to manage forms and also to enhance dynamic forms.

so because the preview component will be another project on its own, I need the best way to pass data from my app into the preview app. Then I thought of passing every form input, cv styles, and data to a redux store so the preview component can just get the user's data from the store

as I said earlier, am using the react hooks form library to manage my form, so to update the store in real-time whenever the user inputs anything, I imported the useWatch hook from react hook form to watch my form in case of any data changes. so I set up a useEffect to listen for any useWatch change to dispatch the whole useWatch data to the store. NB: this data contains an array of objects

my challenge right now is that anytime I dispatch the data to store, redux toolkit or probably immer frowns at what am doing and will always break the app, returning back this error message

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'jobTitle' of object '#<Object>'
    at set (index.esm.mjs?b902:507:1)
    at onChange (index.esm.mjs?b902:1749:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js?ac89:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9097:1)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9288:1)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26140:1)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js?ac89:3991:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9287:1)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js?ac89:6465:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js?ac89:6457:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js?ac89:6430:1)
```

Below is the redux store and how am setting the experience

```
const initialState: IResume = {
  templatePrimaryColor: "#335384",
  top: 0,
  showOverlay: false,
  cv_object: {
    templateId: 1,
    personalInformation: {} as PersonalInformation,
    experiences: [] as Experience[],
    educations: [] as Education[],
    skills: [] as Skill[],
    awards: [] as Award[],
    certificates: [] as Certificate[],
    publications: [] as Publication[],
    references: [] as Reference[],
  },
};


export const resumeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "resume",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setExperience: (state, action: PayloadAction<Experience[]>) => {
      // state.cv_object.experiences = [...action.payload];
      state.cv_object.experiences = Object.assign(state.cv_object.experiences, action.payload);
    },
  },
});
```

Below is how am setting the forms and how am dispatching it

```
 //React hooks form initialSetup
  const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm<CvObject>({
    defaultValues: {
      experiences: [{ ...ExperienceDefaultValues }],
    },
  });

  //usefieldArray for dynamic forms
  const { append, fields, remove } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "experiences" });

  //dispatch the entire form data to experience if any changes is being made
  const formValues = useWatch({ control, name: "experiences" });

  const [currentFormIndex, setCurrentFormIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!useAi) dispatch(hideOverlay());
    else dispatch(showOverlay());
  }, [useAi]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setExperience(formValues));
  }, [formValues]);

  const handleAddAnotherExperience = () => {
    setCurrentFormIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
    append({ ...ExperienceDefaultValues });
  };

  const handleDelete = (index: number) => {
    remove(index);
    if (currentFormIndex > 0) setCurrentFormIndex((prev) => prev - 1);
  };

  const handleEdit = (index: number) => {
    setCurrentFormIndex(index);
  };
```

This is the sample object of the experience am passing but Array of Experience

```
export interface Experience {
  companyName: string;
  fromYear: string;
  toYear: string;
  fromMonth: string;
  toMonth: string;
  currentlyWorking: boolean;
  achievements: string;
  description: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
  index: number;
  jobTitle: string;
}
```

So what am really expecting from this is how to change the store or how to replace the previous experience that is in the store with the incoming experience that is being dispatched.
React hook form is the guy handling new object, removing new object with their useFieldArray hooks.

Comment: Your `action.payload` is of type array but in reducer function you are trying to join two arrays using `Object.assign` which is used to copy one or more source objects to target object. Since your action.payload will have the complete list, you can simply assign your value like this. ` state.cv_object.experiences = action.payload`. Also you do not have to create copy of state as @Obodo David does. Redux toolkit uses immer behind the scenes that's detect changes you make in your state and update it.

Comment: I tried this approach, It didn't work
same error as above

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't directly mutate the data in the redux store, so you can use the object spread operator to create new objects and secondly you should always have a return statement in your slice. So your resumeslice should actually be like this

```
export const resumeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "resume",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setExperience: (state, action: PayloadAction<Experience[]>) => {
       state = {
          ...state,
          cv_object: {
             ...state.cv_object,
             experiences: action.payload
          }
       }

       return state
    },
  },
});
```

I believe this should work

Comment: I read his code but i really thought it should work since he's using @redux-toolkit which is using the immer library which can allow direct state mutation without creating copies of state, I've used this and it works, can i know why it's not working for him?